# Вопрос по фильтрации с помощью mSearch2 на modx

Tags: modx

Возникла необходимость сделать фильтрацию товаров с помощью `mSearch2` примерно такой формы

[image: img]

На сайте подключен `miniShop2 + mSearch2`.
Особенную сложность вызывает реализация фильтра цены "от до"
По выпадающим спискам тоже не совсем понятно как сделать.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать подобный фильтр.

Comment: А у Безумкина спросить? Он придумал платный компонент так пусть осуществляет поддержку.

Comment: Шоп не мой (там все купленное и лицензированное стоит), но меня как фрилансера попросили подправить его и сделать вывод контента из каталога через mSearch2. Все что нужно я подправил, а вот с mSearch2 возникли затруднения, т.к. никогда не работал с этим компонентом.
Поэтому прошу помощи тут